# How do I bind my InputText to a bool using ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

```
<InputText class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" name="validateUSPSAddress" disabled="@true" @bind-Value="_model.CheckUSPSValidation" />
```

In my model, I have defined CheckUSPSValidation as

```
 public bool CheckUSPSValidation { get; set; }
```

The error I receive is the following. I don't understand why it's trying to convert bool to string

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'bool' to
> 'string'  219 N/A

Comment: use `CheckUSPSValidation.ToString()`

Comment: Why not `<InputCheckbox>` ?

Comment: I agree with Brian, you are using the wrong UI component for a boolean.

Comment: Don't mess with basic inputs.  Browsers, especially phone browsers, often have special components for html input, and by-passing them like this could have unfortunate consequences for phone users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert it to bool and back to string. Binding has to be with a string:

```
<EditForm Model="mod">
  <InputText @bind-Value="@mod.checkString"/>
</EditForm>
Value: @mod.check
@code {

MyModel mod = new();
class MyModel
{
    public bool check { get; set; }
    public string checkString{get=>check.ToString();
    set{
        if(Boolean.TryParse(value, out bool val))
        check = val;
    }
    }
}
}
```

[Working demo](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/GPEsEslT46IiXTtb56).